# Is there a Tosofos on Chumash?

Tags: torah-study, pentateuch-chumash, tosfot

I heard from a Rosh yeshiva that there is a commentary from the Tosofos on Chumash that is not widely discussed. Wondering if anyone here is well versed in manuscripts and might be able to comment.

Thanks!

Comment: This? https://www.sefaria.org/Daat_Zkenim_on_Genesis?lang=bi

Comment: I would like to point out that the Daas Zikenim tosefos commentary is found in many, but not all, editions of Mikros Gedolos. In the Meor edition it is at the back of the volume, not on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
It is known as Tosfos HaSholem. You can find it with a simple google search with results such as these:

For example - https://hebrewbooks.org/58885

https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D.html?id=a44QAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y

https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/?q=%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D